# Is there a way to use an array as an address for another array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, memory-address

I am wondering if it is possible to use an array with the same size as the number of dimensions in another array as the original array. I know this is confusing, so I shall illustrate below:

```
program test_pos
implicit none

integer,dimension(4,4) :: holder
integer,dimension(2) :: finder
integer :: row,column

do row=1,size(holder(1,:))
    do column=1,size(holder(:,1))
        holder(column,row)=(row-1)*4+column
    end do
end do

finder=[3,2]

print*,holder
print*,holder(finder)

end program
```

the printout of holder without `print*,holder(finder)` is:

`1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12          13          14          15          16`

The intention of the finder array is to point to an address in the holder array (in this case, the print command should print 7). Eventually, finder will be the output of a function and I don't want to have to run the function twice for every address call in holder, i.e `holder(finder(1),finder(2))`. Compiling the code gives a rank mismatch error (*expletive deleted*). Is there any way around this error/limitation?

Comment: There is no straightforward way to use a rank-1 array, such as `[1,2,3]` to index into a rank-3 array and select `element(1,2,3)`; and the expression `element([1,2,3])` already has an interpretation in Fortran, it refers to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements of a rank-1 array.  It often seems that this is an omission on the part of the people who have defined Fortran down the years.  On the other hand, perhaps its use in your code is the solution to a problem, one you haven't told us about, which does have other solutions.  Perhaps this is an *XY problem* ?

Comment: Closed by someone more familiar with my back catalogue than I am !  Night is drawing in ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Rage, Mark, Rage!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for the help, by the way. I have had a few issues with fortran 'strictness' over the years. I do love it, kinda like a mother loves the black sheep of the family. Honestly, calling the function twice isn't that big of a deal in the code. I was just vainly hoping the array structure of modern fortran would be smarter than this.